# I can't get my WordPress site speed any better

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to improve my load speed on GT Metrix and Pingdom but I can't seem to increase my scores. I tried WP Fastest Cache and WP Rocket but neither of them make a difference (I tried enabling all the features).

My scores on GT Metrix are both E and my Pingdom score is a D.

Any idea why I can't get things like browser caching and expires headers working correctly on my WordPress site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like over 28% of your content is images and 32% is javascript.  That's 60% of your content.  You would be better using a Content Delivery Service such as Clouflare or MaxCDN that can host these on distributed servers.

In WP Rocket, have you tried combining your files such as CSS and Google fonts?

Optimizing website speed takes a lot off effort.  It's rarely just turning on or off one thing.  It's removing and re-evaluating what plugins are necessary, writing your own code instead of using some plugins, and optimizing everything.

Developers also use query strings to prevent browser caching by creating random query strings for each request. Try removing the query string from static files.  You still may end find preventing all browser caching a losing battle for your plugins.